# How to save complex type property as String in a Spring Data MongoDB entity

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

In my Spring Data MongoDB project I have a following POJO:

```
   @Document(collection = "my_entity")
   public class MyEntity {
       private MyProperty myProperty;
   }
```

where MyProperty:

```
   public class MyProperty implements Serializable {
        private String string;
   }
```

When I save instance of such Entiry then in MongoDB it become as following:

```
{ "_id" : ...,
  "myProperty" : {
        "string" : "..."
  }
}
```

How can I have the property "myProperty" saved in such form instead of above, please?:

```
{ 
  "myProperty" : "..."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I have the property "myProperty" saved in such form instead of above, please?:

You can use a custom Converter, which is a Spring Data MongoDB component. It is used to serialise and deserialise objects to and from BSON documents.

You can see the example:

```
public class CustomPropertyConverter implements Converter<MyProperty, String> {

    @Override
    public String convert(MyProperty source) {
        return source.getString();
    }

    @Override
    public MyProperty reverse(String source) {
        MyProperty myProperty = new MyProperty();
        myProperty.setString(source);
        return myProperty;
    }
}
```

Furthermore you need to register this converter with Spring Data MongoDB:

```
@Document(collection = "my_entity")
public class MyEntity {

    @Convert(CustomPropertyConverter)
    private MyProperty myProperty;

    //...
}
```

P.s.
I hope it can help you.

Let me know if it works for you, please.